# Azure Mobile Services - RESTquery return 500 error

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

i'm trying to query some data from my DB in Azure Mobile Services by HTTP request.
when i try something like this:

```
http://MYAPPLICATION.azure-mobile.net/tables/RoutesTrip?$filter=(route_id%20eq%202)
```

i get a good response. but when i try to get this:

```
http://MYAPPLICATION.azure-mobile.net/tables/RoutesTrip?$filter=(route_short_name%20eq%2063)
```

i get error code 500 : "error=Error: Internal Server Error"

at start i had non ASCII letter in this column so i thought that is the problem but i changed it and it still not working.

this column is varchar(50) and also route_id so i don't think this is the problem.

does anyone know why i get this response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing the value in single quotes:

```
http://MYAPPLICATION.azure-mobile.net/tables/RoutesTrip?$filter=(route_short_name%20eq%20'63')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!! but i did some testing and if i have non-ASCII letters in the column i still get this error. do you know how can i fix this?
(i would give you +1 if i had enough reputation,sorry)

Comment: No worries on +1 :). Can you give an example about "non-ASCII letters" in the column?

Comment: hebrew letters like this: 123ב43453א

Comment: My guess is that non-ASCII characters are getting messed up in the URI.  Can you try URLEncoding the value and then sending your request.

Comment: i tried to query some cells with only digits and i got the same response, so i don't think that's it. i think the server is trying to find the string but he get a error when he see non-ASCII letters